# Disable and enable text link with if than else in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

The code as shown below :

CSS:

```
.enableLink{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#069;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.disableLink{
    display:none;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#069;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:default;
}
.btnToPage {
    background-color:#ededed;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#7c7c7c;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    cursor:default;
}

.btnToPage:active {
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #79bbff), color-stop(1, #378de5));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#79bbff', endColorstr='#378de5',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#79bbff;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #84bbf3;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #528ecc;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#378de5', endColorstr='#79bbff',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#378de5;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="enableLink">Enable</span> 
<span class="disableLink">Disable</span>
<div id="btnNext" class="btnToPage">Go to page 2</div>
```

I use javascript to run HTML&CSS, but this code doesn't seems not good and simple.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // JS Enable
    $(".enableLink").click(function(){  
        // Enable Button Go to page 2
        $("#btnNext").removeClass("btnToPage").addClass("myButton");
        $(".enableLink").hide();
        $(".disableLink").show().css({"cursor":"pointer"});
    });
    // JS Disable
    $(".disableLink").click(function(){ 
        // Disable Button Go to page 2
        $("#btnNext").removeClass("myButton").addClass("btnToPage");
        $(".disableLink").hide();
        $(".enableLink").show();
    });
    // Redirect to another page?
    $(".myButton").click(function(){
        window.open("page2.html", target="_self");
    });
});
```

I have 2 questions here. First, how to make the code **if than else** in ***//JS Enable & //JS Disable***. Secondly how to create a correct **redirect link** after **myButton** class active in **enableLink** class.. the last code above can't go to the next page.. what is wrong in the redirect code, those who helped me thank you in advance.

Examples in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kw5nyx4f

Comment: If/else in jquery is the same as many other languages... `if ( condition ) {  stuff; } else { stuff; }`

Comment: and use `window.open("page2.html", "_self");` no need to mention target="...", Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: I was rather difficult to understand JS & Jquery.  I even made the code above to see some tutorials on combining into one. Can you give an example using my code? which is (condition)? and which it {stuff} ?

Comment: @ vijai. remain the same doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify things...

```js
$('span').on('click', function() {
    $("#btnNext").toggleClass("myButton");
    $(this).toggle();
    $('span').not(this).toggle();
  });
  
  $("#btnNext").on('click', function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('myButton')) {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
        } else {
          //Insert click on disabled function here, if any.
          }
 });
```

```css
body { margin: 40px; }

.enableLink{
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#069;
 padding-right:20px;
 text-decoration:underline;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.disableLink{
 display:none;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#069;
 padding-right:20px;
 text-decoration:underline;
 cursor:default;
}
.btnToPage {
 background-color:#ededed;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
 display:inline-block;
 color:#7c7c7c;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:6px 24px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
 cursor:default;
}

.btnToPage:active {
 position:relative;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.myButton {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #79bbff), color-stop(1, #378de5));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#79bbff', endColorstr='#378de5',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#79bbff;
 -moz-border-radius:6px;
 -webkit-border-radius:6px;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:1px solid #84bbf3;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:6px 24px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #528ecc;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#378de5', endColorstr='#79bbff',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#378de5;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="enableLink">Enable</span> 
<span class="disableLink">Disable</span>
<div id="btnNext" class="btnToPage">Go to page 2</div>
```

Merely set the active class to toggle rather than `remove/addClass` this is what the toggle is for.

Altered the click event to merely toggle visibility of the spans. This means you don't need to specific *which* span was clicked. jQuery knows what was clicked and can act upon other similar, unclicked elements.

And I altered the button click, target the ID, not the class. Then check if it's active... and if so.. run the href.

Depending on other elements within the markup, using just the generic `span` for the click event may or may not be an issue. If it is, you can just make both those spans have the same class, and then target the class rather than the span.

Comment: This is what I need, +1 .. now, how to redirect its.

Comment: I am still trying hard to understand the js code that you provide. is there any other examples of joining them to disable / enable / redirect into an if / else. I am very new to toggle Class .. then there hasClass for a class myButton .. looks like I got to learn it even harder. btw thank's for answer

Comment: You can read [jQuery.com](https://jquery.com/) documentation to learn about it's functions and structure.

Comment: Can I ask one more question, what the above code you gave in terms of security is quite good, if the <span> is used as a control to set the link.  is there a web recommendation to understand javascript to be more secure?

Comment: The span isn't setting anything. It's merely changing what is or is not visible on the page. But regardless of it's page visibility, it's still all present in the markup. The link is set in the `#btnNext` function. And while it's possible for that href to be altered... if you aren't storing, passing, reading, or manipulating data it's not really an enticing target for anyone. In addition, if there's no database... or no stored data you are working with, there's customarily not a huge concern about security.

Comment: Okay if span it doesn't affect anything.. for #btnNext and my href code there will be some data on the form that will be stored into the database. This all uses javascript & php.. Actually I wanted to ask a lot about parsing strings using javascript to some data more secure, but I am afraid this is outside the topic of my questions regarding if / else. I had to prepare for this new question on another topic.. @scott, thank's a lot.